# Ubuntu 18.04 Server Beta 2 - restart / reboot not working

Tags: ubuntu-server

I have a fresh install of 18.04 SERVER installed on an Advantech SBC.  16.04 Server was working find but on 18.04 Server when I do a:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The system starts the shutdown but stops with the last status line:

```
[ OK ] Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
```

I've tried some different bios configurations with power management but I can't seem to get it to restart.  Only option at that point is to physically kill power and power up.

Anyone seen this?  Any ideas on what to try?

Comment: The SBC vendor is looking at this.  I can't seem to see anything in the syslog but maybe something has changed in 18.04 on where kernal to bios logging occurs?

Comment: On my SBC setting the South Bridge USB Configuration for Windows 8.x compatibility resolved this issue.  Seems that the V4.15 kernel interactions with hardware are different enough to have caused this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my SBC setting the South Bridge USB Configuration for Windows 8.x compatibility resolved this issue. Seems that the V4.15 kernel interactions with hardware are different enough to have caused this problem.